# Collapsing bootstrap navbar on both tablet and mobile sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]


I want to collapse navbar when screen size is <=750px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's [customization tool](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to build a modified version of Bootstrap. From [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system), you can alter @grid-float-breakpoint to another breakpoint defined by Bootstrap (ie, xs, sm, md, lg).

You need to modified according to highlighted red in below image.

[image: screnshote]

When you're finished, navigate to the [Download](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#download) section, and click On Compile and Download

& then use it bootstrap js & CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you not read the docs?

> ### [Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)
>
> The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than `@grid-float-breakpoint`, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least `@grid-float-breakpoint` in width. Adjust this variable in the [Less](http://lesscss.org/) [source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less) to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is `768px` (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen).